# Npgsql: What's the status of DB Transaction on Postgres DB side, when Rollback failed?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, npgsql

My postgres server version v12, Npgsql 7.0.0 used.

My question goes here: What's the status of DB Transaction on Postgres DB side, when Rollback a `Npgsql.NpgsqlTransaction` fails ?

And what's supposed to be done in that situation ?

Case 1:

```
|2023-01-16 08:51:28.355303 [Ingestion] ERROR [<obfuscated>Apps.<obfuscated>.Ingestion.Core.IngestionBootstrap_23] Run: 
Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Received backend message NoData while expecting CommandCompleteMessage. Please file a bug.
   at Npgsql.Util.Statics.ThrowIfMsgWrongType[T](IBackendMessage msg, NpgsqlConnector connector)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.ExecuteInternalCommand(Byte[] data, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlTransaction.Rollback(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlTransaction.Rollback()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTransaction.Rollback()
   at <obfuscated>.Persistence.Repository.WriteRepository`2.Save(List`1 entities) in D:\repo\ptbuild\PT\Public\Apps\<obfuscated>\<obfuscated>.Persistence.Bulk\Repository\I<obfuscated>WriteRepository.cs:line 64
   at <obfuscated><obfuscated>DivideAndRetrySaveStrategy`1.Save(List`1 entities, Int32 left, Int32 right, Dictionary`2 failed) in D:\repo\ptbuild\PT\Public\Apps\<obfuscated>\<obfuscated>.Ingestion\Ingest\DivideAndRetrySaveStrategy.cs:line 34
   at <obfuscated><obfuscated>DivideAndRetrySaveStrategy`1.Save(List`1 entities) in D:\repo\ptbuild\PT\Public\Apps\<obfuscated>\<obfuscated>.Ingestion\Ingest\DivideAndRetrySaveStrategy.cs:line 29
   at<obfuscated>.OrderIngest.Flush() in D:\repo\ptbuild\PT\Public\Apps\<obfuscated>\<obfuscated>.Ingestion\Ingest\OrderIngest.cs:line 62
   at <obfuscated>Apps.<obfuscated>.Ingestion.Core.<obfuscated>MsgProcessor.FinishLoop() in <obfuscated><obfuscated>MsgProcessor.cs:line 276
   at <obfuscated>Accessor.MonitoringAccessor.MonitoringAccessor.Refresh(IService fromService, DateTime timeStamp)
   at <obfuscated>AccessLayer.Service.Core.DefaultService.Refresh(DateTime timeStamp) in D:\repo\ptbuild\PT\Public\AccessLayer.Service\Core\DefaultService.cs:line 297
   at <obfuscated>Accessor.MonitoringAccessor.Service.MonitoringClientService.Refresh(DateTime now)
   at <obfuscated>Apps.<obfuscated>.Ingestion.Core.IngestionBootstrap.Run() in <obfuscated>IngestionBootstrap.cs:line 137
```

Case 2:

```
|2023-01-13 14:01:37.154638 [Ingestion] ERROR [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command] Failed executing DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TEMP TABLE "#OrdersTemp2811321c" AS TABLE "Orders" WITH NO DATA;
|2023-01-13 14:01:37.163111 [Ingestion] ERROR [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction] An error occurred using a transaction.
|2023-01-13 14:01:37.163637 [Ingestion] ERROR [<obfuscated>Apps.<obfuscated>.Ingestion.Core.IngestionBootstrap_22] Run: 
System.ObjectDisposedException: NpgsqlTransaction
 ---> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while reading from stream
 ---> System.TimeoutException: Timeout during reading attempt
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlReadBuffer.<Ensure>g__EnsureLong|42_0(NpgsqlReadBuffer buffer, Int32 count, Boolean async, Boolean readingNotifications)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|221_0(NpgsqlConnector connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlRaw(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade, String sql, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at EFCore.BulkExtensions.SQLAdapters.PostgreSql.PostgreSqlAdapter.MergeAsync[T](DbContext context, Type type, IList`1 entities, TableInfo tableInfo, OperationType operationType, Action`1 progress, Boolean isAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at EFCore.BulkExtensions.SQLAdapters.PostgreSql.PostgreSqlAdapter.Merge[T](DbContext context, Type type, IList`1 entities, TableInfo tableInfo, OperationType operationType, Action`1 progress)
   at EFCore.BulkExtensions.DbContextBulkTransaction.Execute[T](DbContext context, Type type, IList`1 entities, OperationType operationType, BulkConfig bulkConfig, Action`1 progress)
   at EFCore.BulkExtensions.DbContextBulkExtensions.BulkInsertOrUpdate[T](DbContext context, IList`1 entities, BulkConfig bulkConfig, Action`1 progress, Type type)
   at <obfuscated>.Persistence.Repository.WriteRepository`2.Save(List`1 entities) in D:\repo\ptbuild\PT\Public\Apps\<obfuscated>\<obfuscated>.Persistence.Bulk\Repository\I<obfuscated>WriteRepository.cs:line 62
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlTransaction.CheckDisposed()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlTransaction.CheckReady()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlTransaction.Rollback(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlTransaction.Rollback()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTransaction.Rollback()
   at <obfuscated>.Persistence.Repository.WriteRepository`2.Save(List`1 entities) in D:\repo\ptbuild\PT\Public\Apps\<obfuscated>\<obfuscated>.Persistence.Bulk\Repository\I<obfuscated>WriteRepository.cs:line 62
   at <obfuscated><obfuscated>DivideAndRetrySaveStrategy`1.Save(List`1 entities, Int32 left, Int32 right, Dictionary`2 failed) in D:\repo\ptbuild\PT\Public\Apps\<obfuscated>\<obfuscated>.Ingestion\Ingest\DivideAndRetrySaveStrategy.cs:line 34
   at <obfuscated><obfuscated>DivideAndRetrySaveStrategy`1.Save(List`1 entities) in D:\repo\ptbuild\PT\Public\Apps\<obfuscated>\<obfuscated>.Ingestion\Ingest\DivideAndRetrySaveStrategy.cs:line 29
   at<obfuscated>.OrderIngest.Flush() in D:\repo\ptbuild\PT\Public\Apps\<obfuscated>\<obfuscated>.Ingestion\Ingest\OrderIngest.cs:line 60
   at <obfuscated>Apps.<obfuscated>.Ingestion.Core.<obfuscated>MsgProcessor.FinishLoop() in <obfuscated><obfuscated>MsgProcessor.cs:line 276
   at <obfuscated>Accessor.MonitoringAccessor.MonitoringAccessor.Refresh(IService fromService, DateTime timeStamp)
   at <obfuscated>AccessLayer.Service.Core.DefaultService.Refresh(DateTime timeStamp) in D:\repo\ptbuild\PT\Public\AccessLayer.Service\Core\DefaultService.cs:line 297
   at <obfuscated>Accessor.MonitoringAccessor.Service.MonitoringClientService.Refresh(DateTime now)
   at <obfuscated>Apps.<obfuscated>.Ingestion.Core.IngestionBootstrap.Run() in <obfuscated>IngestionBootstrap.cs:line 136
```

Many thanks!

Comment: A more interesting question is, `What is your code doing?` Why does it use database transactions explicitly? EF Core persists all pending changes in a single internal database transaction when `SaveChanges` is called. There's no reason for `.WriteRepository`2.Save` to call `RollbackTransaction`. In fact, there's usually no reason for an extra Repository - a DbContext already is a multi-entity Repository and Unit-of-Work, a DbSet already is a single-entity Repository

Comment: These are probably not errors generated as a *result* of a rollback, but simply the error that *caused* the rollback, propagated at the end. The stack trace makes that a little hard to determine, though. Note that whether or not the rollback "succeeded", the cornerstone of an RDBMS is that the data is not considered persisted until a successful *commit* happened. Whether or not the rollback failed is immaterial, that only affects the work the engine has to do to make the database consistent again.

Comment: EF isn't a data access library, it's an ORM - Object to Relational Mapper. The data access library is ADO.NET. If you want to ingest a ton of data, an ORM will only cause problems. There are no application object in an ETL operation or rather, the only application objects are Row, Field, Table, File and transformations. If you want to quickly ingest data you need to convert that data into a form that can be passed to `COPY`

Comment: Nothing needs to be done, transaction was not applied. The whole point of transaction is that changes are not applied until commit happens, even if say database dies in the middle of transaction (or in the middle of rollback).

Comment: Regardless of the transaction state, the errors above indicate possible serious errors in user code, e.g. using the same connection instance concurrently from two threads. I'd strongly advise tracking the source of these errors regardless of any transaction status here.

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions is used to achieve bulk operation. The lib use "create temp table >> insert to temp table >> merge temp table to target table " to achieve bulk upsert. And yes  `COPY` is used: COPY BINARY combined with ON CONFLICT for Update.

Comment: @ShayRojansky, ef core create new connection/close connection (if cnx pool disabled); get cnx from pool and return cnx back to pool (if cnx pool is enabled). I'm not in situation concurrently using one db cnx in n threads. 
```
//factory being IDbContextFactory<TDbContext>

using var dbContext = factory.CreateDbContext();
using var transaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction();
try
{
 dbContext.BulkInsertOrUpdate(entities, bulkConfig);
 transaction.Commit();
 
 return true;
}
catch(Npgsql.NpgsqlException exp)
{
 transaction.Rollback();
        return false;
}
```

Comment: `catch (Exception) { transaction.Rollback() }` is a common source of errors. I don't know if Npgsql works correctly with this, but SQL Server at least does not -- the accepted patterns there is to only `.Commit()`, and let the dispose of the `using` take care of rolling back the transaction when it sees no commit has taken place. Otherwise rollback is attempted twice, and you get an unhelpful error when the failed second rollback overwrites the actual error that triggered it. In any case you are dealing with a `DbContext` here and should not be catching provider-specific exceptions.

Comment: you are right @JeroenMostert, thanks. please see my answer below

Comment: @yi.han once again, the errors above indicate a real code bug somewhere; these are not exceptions which you should be catching and handling in code, but rather fixing the bug. The bug may be in the BulkInsertOrUpdate library; I highly recommend putting together a minimal repro and submitting it to the maintainers.